# Cameras and Modelview in OpenGL ES (WebGL)

Tags: opengl-es, matrix, camera, webgl, model-view

I'm having a little trouble with my OpenGL transformations -- I have a vertex shader that sets `gl_Position` to `projection * view * model * vertex`. I have code that generates a view matrix by inverting the model matrix of a camera in space, but when I set the object the camera is looking at to rotate in space, it seems as if the camera is rotating instead.

What could be causing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently I had `projection * model * view * vertex` instead. Oops!